# I am stuck at this error. while I follow all the step to deploy angular app on heroku

Tags: angular, heroku, web-deployment-project

> An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot read property 'Minus' of
> undefined See "/tmp/ng-9JMDN2/angular-errors.log" for further details.
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! syscall spawn npm ERR! file sh npm
> ERR! errno ENOENT npm ERR! qna@0.0.0 heroku-postbuild: `ng build --prod` npm ERR! spawn ENOENT npm ERR!  npm ERR! Failed at the qna@0.0.0 heroku-postbuild script. npm ERR! This is probably not a
> problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above. npm
> ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
> /tmp/npmcache.B2drp/_logs/2021-02-07T16_12_25_425Z-debug.log
> -----> Build failed

```
   We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
   
   If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
   https://help.heroku.com/
   
   Love,
   Heroku
```

!     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
!     Push failed

Comment: Try to do a prod build locally ng build --prod and see if the error is there as well..

Comment: I tried this but there is no error @MikeOne

Comment: I am able to solve the error and able to deploy but problem now is after deploy error message showing "Not Found"  @MikeOne

Answer (score 0):

This resolved for me "ng update @angular/cli @angular/core --allow-dirty --force"

Comment: I am able to solve the error and able to deploy but problem now is after deploy error message showing "Not Found" @opia austin